# "this site has been updated in the background" chrome notification when using php for firebase cloud messaging

Tags: php, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I want to send notifications through firebase to users (Web and Mobile) as i am developing a progressive web app.

I have created a project in Firebase by following their tutorial. Everything is working well, and also i tested sending notification using Curl and it works on Computer and Mobile both properly.

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --header "Authorization: key=<MY-FIREBASE-SERVER-KEY>" \
     -d '{
           "notification": {
             "title": "New Message",
             "body": "Hello, How are you ?",
             "icon": "/images/profile_placeholder.png",
             "click_action": "http://localhost:5000"
           },
           "to": "MY-CLIENT-FCM-TOKEN"
         }' \
     https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

It works properly and shows the notification.

But when I use PHP for sending notification then it sends the notification but with the message as "this site has been updated in the background".

Here is the php file: pwa_demo2.php

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', '<MY-FIREBASE-SERVER-KEY>' );

// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'Hello, How are you ?',
    'title'     => 'New Message'

);
$fields = array
(
    'to'    => 'MY-CLIENT-FCM-TOKEN',
    'data'  => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );

if($result === false)
{
    die('Curl failed: '.curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;

?>
```

So please help me as i am stuck in this for hours...

Comment: While I'm not well-versed in everything used here, it may be worthwhile to take a look at the keys in your array vs the keys in your JSON. Unless both of those structures mean the same thing, you don't seem to be providing the same data in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code is not sending the same message as the CURL command line.

Try printing the output of `json_encode( $fields )` and check if it's the same as the payload that you are passing to the `CURL` command line with the `-d` option